# Collect removes 0 when converting from string to integer

Tags: arrays, ruby, collect

When I use `collect(&:to_i)` to change an array of strings to an array of integers, if the string at index position 0 is "0" it is removed when the array is converted.  For example:

```
n = "0123456789"
number = n.split
array = number.collect(&:to_i)
=> [123456789]
```

chopping off the leading 0.

However if I do this:

```
n = "1230456789"
number = n.split
array = number.collect(&:to_i)
=> [1230456789]
```

and it leaves the 0 in place.

Why is `collect` removing the 0 when it is at position 0 but leaving it alone when it is anywhere else in the array?

Comment: Because a zero in the middle of a number has meaning, but leading zeros do not. This is expected behavior. Don't convert to integers if you care about whether or not the string had a leading zero.

Comment: As pointed out in Brian's answer, the real issue here is that you have a one-element array, but you seem to be expecting a multiple-element array. The single string element gets converted to a single integer element, thus your "problem."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at number in your first example. It is a one element array. So effectively this results in an array with one element: `"0123456789".to_i`

Try this:

```
n = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
numbers = n.split
array = numbers.collect(&:to_i)
```

Comment: Thank You!  I just realized that now.  I also forgot the quotes.  So if I do numbers = n.split ""  it splits the string into an array properly and collect functions as it should.  Punctuation is everything!

Comment: "Let's eat Grandma" -- punctuation saves lives!